# Getting HTML values in Store apps

Tags: c#, html, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am parsing a HTML file from my storage folder. I am going to parse to get some values.

```
StorageFile store = await appfolder.GetFileAsync("01MB154.html");
string content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(store);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(content);
XmlNodeList names = doc.GetElementsByTagName("img");
```

I am getting Exception in  LoadXml(content) line.

**"An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in IMG.exe but was not handled in user code,
Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CE584"**

I tried this answer But not yet worked for me.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188815/hresult-0xc00ce556-loading-string-to-xml)

This is some part from my HTML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="Web Books Publishing" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Main Text</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="figcenter">
<img src="images/img2.jpg"   alt="Cinderella" title="" />
</div>
```

I checked some files which I want to work with, not yet fine.
I want to know there is any other way to getting HTML values.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You HTML is not well formed according to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

Try with this

```
StorageFile store = await appfolder.GetFileAsync("01MB154.html");
string content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(store);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

XmlLoadSettings loadSettings = new XmlLoadSettings();
loadSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;

doc.LoadXml(content, loadSettings);
XmlNodeList names = doc.GetElementsByTagName("img");
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here's my working code

```
StorageFile store = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("01MB154.html");
string content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(store);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlLoadSettings loadSettings = new XmlLoadSettings();
loadSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;
doc.LoadXml(content, loadSettings);
XmlNodeList names = doc.GetElementsByTagName("img");
```

**UPDATE 2**

replace `&nbsp;` to `&amp;nbsp;`, it worked for me.

Comment: @Xyroid Hi,I changed the settings not yet worked for me. this time
Changes the exception number **Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CE002**
In the W3Schools I checked to validate my html data it is giving no errors.
I am expecting is there any other solution for it.
Thanks.

Comment: can you please give me whole html file ?

Comment: 0xC00CE002 references to undefined entity. If your XML contains '&', '<', '>' then you need to escape those entities. Like '&' must be replaced with '&amp;' like that.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
In the mean while I checked my few files. If file contains '&' like things it is giving exception. Remaining are fine, 
This is one of the file I am facing the problem. [http://sdrv.ms/12TTVX3 ] 
Can you give an idea to replace these values.

Comment: I didn't faced any problem with file "01MB154.html", did you used my solution with "01MB154.html"? [Different ways how to escape an XML string in C#](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx)

Comment: yes, I used. From starting I am using that file only.
if you don't mind can you post your code which you tried work in [http://pastebin.com/ ]. Thanks

Comment: @Xyroid oh,my bad. It's my mistake. the file which I shared to you is a edited file to check whether what happened `<p>&nbsp;</p>` these type of lines. I commented these lines in that line.  I changed the html file source. [http://sdrv.ms/18fGkhp ] 
I apologize for that... Can you check now.