# Reading xml file causes HRESULT: 0xC00CE556

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am writing a Windows 8.1 store app and I need to read a local xml file produces a general error trying to load the file.

Here's the file and code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\eventList2.xml");


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EventList>1</EventList>
```

Comment: Martin, it's a better practice to put the issue into the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks carlodurso. This is my first question. I'll try and work out how to move it into the body

Comment: keyboard. I looked at that question you referred to and it says that was an extra '?' at the beginning of the file. Mine does not.

Comment: The answer suggested by @keyboard indeed shows a way to load XML in store app. If you insist on using `LoadXml` just read file as text first and than feed to `LoadXml` (as shown in suggestion 1 of the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13192110/477420).

Answer (score 1):

doc.LoadXml() expects XML string as parameter. To load XML from file, use doc.Load(@"C:...");

Comment: If I change to doc.Load(@"C... then I get a  compile error stating that Load method could not be found in Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument

Comment: The class is System.Xml.XmlDocument