# Loading XML not working: Invalid at the top level of the document

Tags: xml, vba, excel, resx, msxml2

I want to parse and modify the following `.resx` file using `Excel VBA`.

The `.resx` is exactly like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <!-- 
    Microsoft ResX Schema 

    Version 2.0

    The primary goals of this format is to allow a simple XML format 
    that is mostly human readable. The generation and parsing of the 
    various data types are done through the TypeConverter classes 
    associated with the data types.

    Example:

    ... ado.net/XML headers & schema ...
    <resheader name="resmimetype">text/microsoft-resx</resheader>
    <resheader name="version">2.0</resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>
    <data name="Name1"><value>this is my long string</value><comment>this is a comment</comment></data>
    <data name="Color1" type="System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing">Blue</data>
    <data name="Bitmap1" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
        <value>[base64 mime encoded serialized .NET Framework object]</value>
    </data>
    <data name="Icon1" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
        <value>[base64 mime encoded string representing a byte array form of the .NET Framework object]</value>
        <comment>This is a comment</comment>
    </data>

    There are any number of "resheader" rows that contain simple 
    name/value pairs.

    Each data row contains a name, and value. The row also contains a 
    type or mimetype. Type corresponds to a .NET class that support 
    text/value conversion through the TypeConverter architecture. 
    Classes that don't support this are serialized and stored with the 
    mimetype set.

    The mimetype is used for serialized objects, and tells the 
    ResXResourceReader how to depersist the object. This is currently not 
    extensible. For a given mimetype the value must be set accordingly:

    Note - application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64 is the format 
    that the ResXResourceWriter will generate, however the reader can 
    read any of the formats listed below.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized with 
            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.soap.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized with 
            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized into a byte array 
            : using a System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.
    -->
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <data name="Change_phone_number" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Change phone number</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Change_your_mobile_phone_number" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Please change your mobile phone number</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

The VBA code looks like this:

```
Sub ReadXMLDateFromFiles()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim XDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Files")
XDoc.async = False: XDoc.validateOnParse = False

i = 2
Do While ws.Cells(1, i).Value <> ""
    XDoc.Load ws.Cells(1, i).Value
    XDoc.LoadXML ws.Cells(1, i).Value
    Debug.Print XDoc.parseError.reason, XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode
    i = i + 1
Loop
Set XDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

As mentioned in the heading, the error:

```
Error message: Invalid at the top level of the document
Error code: -1072896682
```

I am not sure why I receive the error message.

Removing the commentary part as well as the `<xsd:>` tags does not help either.

I have tried the code with other XML files and it works. I have changed the ending of the file to xml and it doesn't work.

I don't know what else to try. The file is saved as UTF8. I can open it in Webstorm without a problem and it is being recognized.

The XPath I would want to use: `XDoc.SelectNodes("/root/data[@name='Change_phone_number']/value")`

I have the following start in the document in `notepad++`: [image]

Comment: Searching the error code (it translates to an HRESULT of 0xC00CE556) [turned this up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188815/hresult-0xc00ce556-loading-string-to-xml). Are you getting a BOM marker at the start of the string?

Comment: Can you give a single example of one part of the above that you want to alter and what you want to alter it to please? A currently failing example. Include the actual values. I can load this just fine.

Comment: @Comintern, thanks a lot for the link, I will have a look. @qharr this is weird, but might have to do with the above. I would want to alter the 
`<data name="Change_phone_number"><value>` field.

Comment: What is weird? Sorry I may have missed something.

Comment: And did you want to change:  <value>Change phone number</value>  or <data name="Change_phone_number"><value> ?

Comment: My mistake, the XML load method did not work as expected, using regular Load worked fine with a second file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works perfectly for me, reading your xml from a file on desktop

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()
    Dim xDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, node As IXMLDOMElement

    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With xDoc
        .async = False
        .validateOnParse = True

        If Not xDoc.Load("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Testing.xml") Then
            Debug.Print .parseError.reason, .parseError.ErrorCode
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Set node = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data[@name='Change_phone_number']")

        If Not node Is Nothing Then
            node.Text = "Ain't nobody got time for that"
        End If
        Debug.Print node.Text
    End With
End Sub
```